# How can I determine if I am running a side-loaded app or a Store-installed app?

Tags: windows-store-apps

For the sake of testing, knowing that I am running from Visual Studio would be nice. I could see if the debugger is attached, but that is not sufficient if I am running with CTRL+F5.

Here's how to see if the debugger is attached:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached) Foo();
```

But my question is, I wonder if there is a way to ask if the current app is from the Store. So, I thought about install folder, but they are identical. Then I thought about this:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id;
```

But this appears to be completely implemented even for apps that are being debugged. So, I am stumped. Does anyone know if we can determine if the app is from the Store?

Answer (score 2):

While certainly not the most elegant solution and there's probably a better one, you can check

```
Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path
```

If you are running a debug build developed on your local machine and not side loaded, you'll have /debug/ in your folder path.

Comment: Another idea if "WindowsApps" is in the path above (or if you want to be specific expand %programfiles%\windowsapps), then either it's sideloaded or from the Windows Store or the user changed the WindowsApps folder in the registry. This would handle release mode and debug mode applications as well.

Comment: What if I side-loaded a release build?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 apps (this also should be available in 8.1), you can check the `IsDevelopmentMode` property on the current package.

`Package.Current.IsDevelopmentMode`

That should tell you whether the package was installed in development mode (which I believe is synonymous with 'side-loaded').

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.isdevelopmentmode.aspx
for more information.